# Equals operator on subclass as well as abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-overloading

Let's say we have the following simple classes:

```
abstract class Abc { }

class Bcd : Abc { public int val; }
```

By default, the `==` operator on `Bcd` instances will return false in this example:

```
var result_1 = new Bcd() { val = 10 } == new Bcd() { val = 10 };
```

So, following the guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) the `==` operator can be added to `Bcd`:

```
class Bcd : Abc
{
    public int val;

    public bool Equals(Bcd obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return false;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, this)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        return obj.val == val;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Bcd);

    public override int GetHashCode() => val.GetHashCode();

    public static bool operator ==(Bcd a, Bcd b)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(b, null)) return true;

            return false;
        }

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Bcd a, Bcd b) => !(a == b);
}
```

And now, the expression evaluates to true:

```
var result_1 = new Bcd() { val = 10 } == new Bcd() { val = 10 };
```

However, I may want to store instances of `Bcd` (and perhaps other instances of other subclasses of `Abc`) in variables typed as `Abc`:

```
Abc a = new Bcd() { val = 10 };
Abc b = new Bcd() { val = 10 };
```

Now, this of course will return false:

```
var result_2 = a == b;
```

One way to get the desired behaviour is to add equality methods to `Abc` as well (even though it is an abstract class):

```
abstract class Abc
{
    public bool Equals(Abc obj)
    {
        if (obj is Bcd && this is Bcd) return (obj as Bcd) == (this as Bcd);

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Abc a, Abc b)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(b, null)) return true;

            return false;
        }

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Abc a, Abc b) => !(a == b);
}
```

Now the expression returns `true`:

```
Abc a = new Bcd() { val = 10 };
Abc b = new Bcd() { val = 10 };

var result_2 = a == b;
```

My question is, is adding the equality operator (and `Equals` method, `!=` operator, etc.) to the abstract parent class `Abc` in the above way the recommended approach? It feels a little boilerplate-ish. Moreover, if `Abc` is subclassed again in the future, the `Equals` operator in `Abc` needs to be updated; this also feels a little odd.

Is there any recommended guide for this pattern?

Comment: I can recomend you to look at [EqualityComparer<T> abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of overriding objects `Equals` method.

Comment: I don’t think that’s a good idea. For example, you cannot say that two animals are the same if they have four legs and a tail, you have to be specific.

Comment: i'd also keep them in the derived classes. One reason we use an abstract/derived relationship is to be able to discriminate between similar, but different types. If they're different enough that you designed them as separate classes, they should be compared against the same derived types. If you need to know whether two objects share the same base class there's other options for that.

Comment: also, if you do go the route of defining it in the base, it might work okay right now and make sense. But in the future if you have to add more derived types and all of a sudden the previous implementation doesn't make sense anymore, you've created a burden on yourself to fix the bug and somehow have to manage creating the equality logic that makes sense for N derived types